# Aspose.Words - Range.Parse(regex, value, FindReplaceOptions) method can't find text specified with regex in paragraph but in table cell it does

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I wrote simple word document with one paragraph and one table (with one cell) under that paragraph. I'm using Aspose 16.7 and Aspose 22.9 (on both versions I have same problem).

When I open that word document using aspose it will look like this:

```
\r\r\r<<AC:doc_title:value>>\r<<AC:doc_title:value>>\a\a\rTest\r\r\r
```

Replace method won't work when it tries to find and replace *<<AC:doc_title:value>>* which is in paragraph but when I put same tag in table cell, replace method will find that tag and replace it with given text. This is my replace method call:

```
node.Range.Replace(new Regex("<<AC:doc_title:value>>"), "Replaced text", new FindReplaceOptions(FindReplaceDirection.Forward));
```

I tried to call Parse method with different FindReplaceOptions but that didn't give any results.
I also tried Replace method with only two parameters, *node.Range.Replace(new Regex("<<AC:doc_title:value>>"), value)* and when using  this method, I didn't have any problems, it works fine (but problem is that method is **Obsolete** now).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.Replace(Regex, string)` overload is no marked as obsolete. So you can use it:
https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/range/replace/#replace_2

This overload internally calls the overload with `FindReplaeOptions`, so both should work the same:

```cs
public int Replace(Regex pattern, string replacement)
{
    return Replace(pattern, replacement, new FindReplaceOptions());
}
```

If you still has problems, please post the question in [Aspose.Words support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8) and attach your input document there for testing.

Comment: Are you sure that this method is not obsolete, why is it then underlined in visual studio and it suggest me to use another Replace method with FindReplaceOptions parameter.

[Obsolete("Use Replace(Regex pattern, string replacement, FindReplaceOptions options).")].

Thanks for your answer, I will then use this Range.Replace(Regex, string) method and maybe I will ask same question on aspose forum.

Comment: I see it is marked as obsolete in 16.7 version. But in the latest version it is not marked as obsolete. looks like it was marked as obsolete by mistake.

Comment: We are moving to aspose 22.9 so info that this method is not obsolete anymore is great. Thanks!